# Can I use frozen vegetables in smoothies?

Tags: vegetables, frozen, smoothie

I add frozen broccoli, spinach, kale, carrots, squash and cauliflower to my smoothies raw. Is that bad to do? The packaging says cook to 165 degrees. How likely am I to get sick from this? What if I rinse the frozen vegetables under cold water first, would that help chances of hepatitis or ecoli whatever? The frozen strawberries don't say 'cook to 165' isn't the risk the same with the frozen fruit? Why do I have to cook one not the other?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Food safety issues related to eating raw frozen vegetables](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/56115/food-safety-issues-related-to-eating-raw-frozen-vegetables)

Comment: The suggested duplicate doesn't mention anything about frozen fruit (e.g. strawberries) which leaves me rather curious about whether strawberries should be treated similarly or not, and therefore wondering whether my smoothie recipes are safe or not... :)